# how to Create a Grunt File

Tags: gruntjs

The  index file for my angular app looks something like below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!--  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>

</head>

<body style="padding:10px;" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div ng-include="'toolbar.tpl.html'"></div>

  <div ui-view></div>

<hr>

  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12"> 

      This is the footer section
    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- closing class="container-fluid"

<!-- Included for ui-date -->  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.layout-latest.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>


<!-- Main Module here -->
<script src="js/resources/resources.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>


<!-- Employee Module here -->
<script src="js/employee/employeeCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/employee/employeeEditCtrl.js"></script>

<!-- Machine's Module here -->

<!-- Supplier's Module here -->

<!-- Customers's Module here -->

<!-- Common Modules here -->
<script src="js/globalservices.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is just a snapshot of it. I have removed a lot of modules from the code above to make the question legible. The folder structure looks like the attached snapshot.

The index file I believe has become un-manageable.What I want to do next is create a grunt file. I am not sure where to get started. Any advise will be appreciated.

Thanks,[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to plan what do you want as result: a minified javascript, only one with all other concatenated, unit tests and so forth.

Starting with a concatenated version, you'll need the grunt-contrib-concat to merge all of them into one single file that you'll reference inside your index.html.

Link for Grunt Getting Started: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
Link for Grunt Concat: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat